# Android Photosphere Code Samples

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk, photosphere

I'm looking for good Android code samples for Photosphere, particularly for Google Glass if possible.  I've found some basic documentation here https://developers.google.com/photo-sphere/android/ and here http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/panorama/package-summary.html, but I can't find anything comprehensive enough to get me started.

Does anyone know of any good code samples?  Or is Photosphere development on Glass even available yet (I know of the [photosphere easter egg](http://www.geek.com/mobile/the-glass-photosphere-easter-egg-every-android-device-should-have-1555751/), but can't find a way to code it myself)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photosphere was only added into the settings of Google Glass specifically for the easter egg. It is much like Google Play Services near the beginning. They built their own version for there use and that is it. Development for it is not supported and not accessible by any third party applications.